# rabbitmq multiple consumers on a queue- only one get the message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I implemented multiple consumers, who are fetching messages from a single queue,  I am doing this using something similar to [this example](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_basic_get.html), except that I'm doing basic.get on an infinite loop for polling.

Any idea how do I prevent racing between all consumers, in that only one consumer will get the message and the other will continue to do polling until another message comes?
I tried implementing a logic in which as soon as I get the message I ack it for the message to be removed, but it seems that some other queue managed to get the message before the first queue has ack and removed it.
So each consumer got the message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you publishing the message on the queue? How are you consuming it? Do I understand correctly that _all_ your consumers receive the message, and not just one - but you want only one client to receive it? Or do only one client receive the message, and you want everyone to receive it?

Comment: Publishing using channel.basic_publish -direct with routing_key
consuming it using basic_get, exactly like in the example above

Comment: All my consumers receive the message , and I want that the first who got it will process it, and that only one consumer will get every message from the queue, the one who is available

Answer (score 16):

> Any idea how do I prevent racing between all consumers, in that only one consumer will get the message and the other will continue to do polling until another message comes?

you can't, the way you have things set up. RabbitMQ will round-robin the messages to the consumers, but only one consumer will receive the message from the queue. This is by design in RabbitMQ, when you have multiple consumers on a single queue.

If you need all consumers to receive all messages, then you need to change your configuration so that each consumer has it's own queue. Then you need to publish your message through an exchange that will deliver the message to all of the queues for all of the consumers.

The easiest way to do this is with a Fanout exchange type.

Comment: "but only one consumer will receive the message from the queue" that's exactly what I want, and it didn't happen. Anyway I added `channel.basiq_qos(prefetch_count=1)` and now it seems that only one consumer get the message and not all of them

Comment: Setting `prefetch_count` to `1` on a channel and having multiple consumers on that channel with `auto_ack` turned off will do the job. Only one active consumer will hold a message while other will be waiting. Note, that it only works when consumers are on the same channel. But if they are on the same channel and you need process message only by 1 consumer at a time, I guess it makes sense just run single consumer. Also, take a look on queue's `exclusive` parameter, in some situations it may be a solution.

Comment: @zaq178miami: I'm little confused , problem is that, I have 2 queues  and multiple consumers on each queue, I want to that when message arrive to queue X -> only one of the active consumers will take the message, and others will continue waiting , until next message of course, then the same story

Comment: By the way currently it seems that  I also see that each consumer opens new channel and new connection, should I use the same channel for each queue?
How can I do that if I ran the consumer files on different processes multiple times?