# RabbitMQ - Need Channel per Machine?

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, amqp

We have multiple backend machines. The goal is to have each machine pick up each message sent to a single RabbitMQ exchange.

The `FooExchange` is set to `fanout` (so it sends a message to all the queues connected to it). `FooExchange` has one queue, `FooQueue`, which is bound to it. All our machines are consumers of `FooQueue`.

This works fine locally, but when we have multiple machines in play, it *appears* that only ONE machine picks up the message at a time. It picks up the message specifically 1 time / however many machines there are. This is corroborated by an old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864644/rabbitmq-multiple-consumers-on-a-queue-only-one-get-the-message).

I have several questions:

1. Is creating a queue per machine the best way to proceed?
2. The "machines" are actually going to be K8S pods - what should I use as a unique machine identifier in the queue name? Or just make instantiate a GUID and call it a day?
3. Finally, how do I handle pod restarts (if unfamiliar with K8S, think of a cloud load balancer spinning up new VM instances) - this will leave dead queue as the replacement pods/VMs create new ones to consume from.

Comment: I think you mean "queue", not "channel". A [channel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html) is the logical connection a consumer uses inside a physical [connection](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connections.html). [Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html) is what you are asking about.

Comment: Right. I made a mistake in #2. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** A fanout exchange routes all messages to all bound queues. So the answer to your first question depends on what you want to achieve. If you want *every* consumer to receive *every* message, use a fantout exchange, create a queue for every consumer, bind it to the exchange. The let each consumer exclusively consume the messages from his queue.

If on the other hand you want every message to be consumed by only once, use a single queue and let all consumers consume messages from it. This will use the default round-robin behaviour: the consumers are taking turns and every message is consumed exactly once.

**2)** If you use the first approach, you can let the queue names be automatically generated for every consumer upon queue creation. This name will be fine and unique.

**3)** RabbitMQ supports [temporary queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#temporary-queues) which are deleted when the consumer goes away. If you require every message to be consumed at least once, make sure to declare a [dead letter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for messages that could not be consumed by a consumer that went away. This will enable you to reroute such messages.

Comment: I ended up setting `autoDelete` to `true`. It's supposed eliminate the queue once the last connection to it is closed, which seems to support my requirement for not filling up Rabbit with dead Queue for VMs which go down.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create `FooQueue` in every backend machine. RabbitMQ can support multiple connections. You can start a `RabbitMQ consumer` in each one of the backend machines. Make sure each `consumer` opens a new connection and consumes from the queue. If you want your consumer to consume one message at a time, set the basic.

Comment: This is how it's set up already - only one VM picks up a single message, after which it is removed from the queue. The goal is to have all VMs pick up the message.